# how to modify product detail image size in PWA?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, pwa

I have an issue, I found the image's width and height defined in the peregrine folder, but I don't know how to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

productFullDetail.css

Changing max-width takes effect

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .imageCarousel {
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 1100px;
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
    }
}
```